# I renamed my app and now I can't release build in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, apk, phonegap-build, signing

I am trying to build my android app for the play store,
The app is build in cordova v5.3.3.

I am able to build a signed release version of my app, however if I import it in the play.developer website I get this error:

> Upload failed
>   Your APK must have the package name com.NEXTapp.app.
>   You
>   must use a different versioncode for your APK since there allready is
>   an APK with versioncode 48.

When I created the cordova project I had com.COMPANYapp.app set as package name, my guess is that the change in package names is the cause of my problems.

I can edit the versioncode and package name entries in my androidManifest.xml file but as soon as I run the build android --release command it gets reverted.

Can someone help me sign this app with the right versioncode and packagename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation of the config.xml file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/config_ref/).

Cordova uses this information when building.

**Edit (more details:)** For example:

```
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@callback.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

The id and the version information will be used for building the release.

Comment: Thanks Andre, one minute after posting this question the config.xml file sprang to mind.
I will accept your answer, but could you flesh it out a bit more? cordova tends to change their links from time to time.